# working with tabs in selenium webdriver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a Firewall, I want to open a set of pages simultaneously each in a new tab, then save a tab id in threads and then when threads finished, analyze tabs one by one. here is a sample code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'thread'
mutex = Mutex.new
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["webdriver.load.strategy"] = "unstable";
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox,:profile => profile
max = 100;
th = []
max.times{ |i|
   th[i] = Thread.new {
      mutex.synchronize do
        # TODO browser.open_new_tab 
        # TODO Thread.current["tab_id"] =  browser.get_tab_id
        Thread.current["i"] =  i
        browser.get("http://foo.bar?id=#{i}")
      end
   }
   sleep 2
}

th.each{|t|
   t.join
   tab = t["tab_id"]
   # TODO browser.open_tab(tab)
   analyse_content # method
}
```

what should i use in `TODO` lines?

ATTENTION: Since I'm using multi threading, i dont want to use `alt` + `tab`

Comment: You are testing a firewall? For what? Performance? Sounds like Selenium isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: i cant explain. important thing is that i want to manage tabs.

Comment: Then try. The fact you are also hacking it about using the `webdriver.load.strategy` is showing this really isn't the tool for the job. On the face of it this looks like performance testing. Nonetheless, none of the drivers support tabs, they are usually just treated as new windows. So have a search around about how to switch to a new window using Selenium